# How to update a field in Fauna Database

Tags: reactjs, database, querying, faunadb, fql.multiquery

I am working in fauna DB. I have a confusion for writing an query to update a field . From the given array object I want to update the Boolean fields ( "presentation", "keyTakeaways", "whitepaper",  "downloadAll") with the reference to the **SegmentAnonymousID**. I am adding the code that I tried. Can someone help me to sort out the problem.

```
[{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("Downloads"), "322568726157197900"),
  "ts": 1643884359510000,
  "data": {
    "SegmentAnonymousID": "57f22fc0-2ace-4522-b0a6-4d0cd45cfc3a",
    "response": {
      "firstname": "test ",
      "lastname": "test 1",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "company": "test",
      "presentation": false,
      "keyTakeaways": false,
      "whitepaper": false,
      "downloadAll": false
    }
  }
},
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("Downloads"), "322484599970071113"),
  "ts": 1643870069845000,
  "data": {
    "SegmentAnonymousID": "15ba9e0d-e646-4d31-beaa-b2a4d3eac56f",
    "response": {
      "firstname": "test 4",
      "lastname": "test4",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "company": "test",
      "presentation": false,
      "keyTakeaways": false,
      "whitepaper": false,
      "downloadAll": false
    }
  }
}]
```

*The code I tried*

```
 

     const result = await faunaClient.query(
                q.Update(
                    q.Select("ref", q.Get(q.Match(q.Index("SegmentAnonymousID"), "57f22fc0-2ace-4522-b0a6-4d0cd45cfc3a")), { data: { response: { "presentation": true } } })
                )
            )
```

Comment: Your update query looks appropriate at first glance.  Can you please share what your problem actually is?  It would be good to state what you expect to happen and what is actually happening, including any errors that you receive.

The definition of your Index may also be relevant.  Can you post the output from running `Get(Index("SegmentAnonymousID"))`?

Answer (score 2):

Your query has brackets in the wrong place. As written, the object containing the new data appears as the "default" value for the `Select` call. You'll likely have better success with this update (reformatted to show function calls and parameters better):

```
const result = await faunaClient.query(
  q.Update(
    q.Select(
      "ref",
      q.Get(
        q.Match(
          q.Index("SegmentAnonymousID"),
          "57f22fc0-2ace-4522-b0a6-4d0cd45cfc3a"
        )
      )
    ),
    {
      data: {
        response: {
          presentation: true
        }
      }
    }
  )
)
```